# add two elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have create a nested directive (a multitabbed form directive), here is simplified:

```
<outer>
  <inner heading="a" src="'a.html'" active="true"></inner>
  <inner heading="b" src="'b.html'"></inner>
</outer>
```

This create `ul/li` tabset, when I click on tab the `li` will be `active` and `div` related to that tab will become visible too.

This is my directives:

```
(function(){
  'use strict'

  angular 
    .module("testDirective", [])
    .directive("outer", outer)
    .directive("inner", inner);

  function outer(){
    return {
      templateUrl: 'outer.html', 
      transclude: true,
      controller: function($scope){
        var tabs = $scope.tabs = [];  
        this.addTab = function(_active, _name) {
          tabs.push({
            active : _active,  
            name : _name
          }); 
        }  

        $scope.toggle = function(ix){
          for (var i = 0; i <= tabs.length - 1; i++) {
                    tabs[i].active = false; 
                } 

                tabs[ix].active = true;
        }  
      } 
    }
  } 

  function inner(){
    return {
      require: '^outer',
      scope: {
        src : '=',
        active : '=',
      },
      templateUrl: 'inner.html',
      link : function(s, e, a, ctrl) {  
        ctrl.addTab(a.active, a.heading); 
      }
    }
  } 
})();
```

I successfully implement everything except one part that cause me headaches: how can I show/hide content? This is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WHSA0MkWZWiIzDqwj6CF?p=preview).

Comment: You want to bind `active` to something shared among `inner` objects. It might be awkward with the `ng-include` setup provided, but have you tried passing a `tab` object to each `inner` element? That way you have access to its active status within the `inner` element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

Modification to index.html:

```
<outer>
  <inner heading="a" src="'a.html'" index="0" active=true></inner>
  <inner heading="b" src="'b.html'" index="1"></inner>
</outer>
```

InnerHTML:

```
<ng-include ng-class="isActive()" src="src"></ng-include>
```

Added the following function to outer function:

```
this.isActive = function (index) {
      if(tabs[index] && tabs[index].active){
        return "ng-show";
      } else {
        return "ng-hide";
      }
};
```

Added modified inner link function like so:

```
link : function(s, e, a, ctrl) {  
    ctrl.addTab(a.active, a.heading);
    s.isActive = function () {
      return ctrl.isActive(a.index);
    };
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/c311iIKEGRGyBPMFbzi8?p=preview

Comment: This do the job but the `index` attribute don't make me happy and I will try to calculate it behind the scene :)

Comment: You can loop through a list for that too depending on whether the data for the various tab content can be stored as a list. I am also a beginner in Angular hence my apologies if there are mistakes in my implementation.